# TabBar tappedIcon unTappedIcon Issue

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbar, xcode9

When i tapped on my TabBar's first image it should be highlighted like the below image - 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxbPd.png)

But when i tap on the first icon it's doing nothing, tap on the second icon it's highlighting the first icon, tap on the 3rd icon highlighting it's previous icon (second icon) and so on. It might be an indexing problem. Need some help to find this issue. Thank you. My TabBar current view-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7KJW.png)

Here is my code -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: BaseViewController {
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet var warningsIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var incidentsIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var notificationsIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var myMessagesIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var warningsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var incidentsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var notificationsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myMessagesTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    //MARK: PROPERTIES
     var previousSelectedIcon:UIImageView!
     var previousSeelctedTitle:UILabel!
     var previousIndex:Int!
     var currentIndex:Int!
     var previousVc:UIViewController!
    fileprivate var i = 0
    open var subViewController:UIViewController?
    var unTappedIcon = ["warnings","incidents","notifications","my-messages"]
    var tappedIcon = ["warnings_tapped","Incidents_tapped","notifications_tapped","myMessages_tapped"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        previousVc = self;

        previousSelectedIcon = warningsIcon
        previousSeelctedTitle = warningsTitle

        previousIndex = 0;
        currentIndex = 0;

        //place sub view controller if any
        placeSubViewControllerIfNeeded()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //place sub view controller if needed
    func placeSubViewControllerIfNeeded() -> Void{
        if let vc = subViewController {
            vc.view.frame = self.containerView.frame
            self.addChildViewController(vc)
            //vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
            self.view.sendSubview(toBack: vc.view)
        }
    }


    //MARK: For Tab bar
     func updateTapView(title:UILabel, icon:UIImageView) {

        previousSeelctedTitle.textColor = UIColor(red:0.60, green:0.60, blue:0.60, alpha:1.0)
        previousSelectedIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: unTappedIcon[previousIndex])

        title.textColor = UIColor(red:0.26, green:0.18, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)
        icon.image = UIImage.init(named: tappedIcon[currentIndex])
    }

    func removePreviousViewController() {
        previousVc.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        previousVc.view.removeFromSuperview()
        previousVc.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    func getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier:String)->UIStoryboard {
        return  UIStoryboard.init(name: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    func showSubViewContrller(subViewController:UIViewController) {

        self.addChildViewController(subViewController)

        subViewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        self.containerView.addSubview(subViewController.view)

        subViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        previousVc = subViewController
    }



    //Mark:- Action button for warnings
    @IBAction func onClickWarnings(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hi there i am just a warning")

        self.warningsIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: "warnings_tapped")
        previousIndex = currentIndex
        currentIndex = 0
        updateTapView( title: warningsTitle, icon: warningsIcon)

        previousSeelctedTitle = warningsTitle
        previousSelectedIcon = warningsIcon

        if i > 0{
            removePreviousViewController()
            print("i am already removed")
        }

        let storyBoard = getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier: "warnings")
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WarningsViewController") as! WarningsViewController
        showSubViewContrller(subViewController: vc)

        i += 1
    }

    //Mark:- Action button for warnings
    @IBAction func onClickIncidents(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hi there i am just a warning")

        self.incidentsIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: "Incidents_tapped")
        previousIndex = currentIndex
        currentIndex = 1
        updateTapView( title: incidentsTitle, icon: incidentsIcon)

        previousSeelctedTitle = incidentsTitle
        previousSelectedIcon = incidentsIcon

        if i > 0{
            removePreviousViewController()
            print("i am already removed")
        }


        let storyBoard = getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier: "incidents")
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IncidentsViewController") as! IncidentsViewController
        showSubViewContrller(subViewController: vc)

        i += 1

    }

    //Mark:- Action button for warnings
    @IBAction func onClickNotifications(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Really true")
      self.notificationsIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: "notifications_tapped")
        previousIndex = currentIndex
        currentIndex = 2
        updateTapView(title: notificationsTitle, icon: notificationsIcon)

        previousSeelctedTitle = notificationsTitle
        previousSelectedIcon = notificationsIcon

        if i > 0 {
            removePreviousViewController()
            print("I am already removed")
        }

        let storyBoard = getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier: "notifications")
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationsViewController") as! NotificationsViewController
        showSubViewContrller(subViewController: vc)

        i += 1
    }

    //Mark:- Action button for warnings
    @IBAction func onClickMyMessages(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("ha ha..i believe in that")
        self.myMessagesIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: "myMessages_tapped")
        previousIndex = currentIndex
        currentIndex = 3
        updateTapView(title: myMessagesTitle , icon: myMessagesIcon)

        previousSeelctedTitle = myMessagesTitle
        previousSelectedIcon = myMessagesIcon

        if i > 0 {
            removePreviousViewController()
            print("i am alreday removed")
        }

        let storyBoard = getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier: "myMessages")
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyMessagesViewController") as! MyMessagesViewController
        showSubViewContrller(subViewController: vc)

        i += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: I think Remove previousIndex = 0;  currentIndex = 0; from viewDidLoad , declare it above Class For example var previousIndex = 0

Comment: Nothing changed. Same as before @NilomiShah

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding view ineach viewcotroller which you want to show as if a tab bar item.. this might not be the right way to do.. what you can do is make your custom tabbar controller

```
class SampleViewController: UITabBarController {

@IBOutlet var tabBarView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var item1Btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var item2Btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var item3Btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var item4Btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var item5Btn: UIButton!


let item1Image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profileUnselected")
let item1Selected = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile")
let item2Image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notificationUnselected")
let item2Selected = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notificationSelected")
let item3Image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "game")
let item3Selected = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "game")
let item4Image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cookbooksUnselected")
let item4Selected = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cookbooks")
let item5Image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "searchTabUnselected")
let item5Selected = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "searchTabSelected")

let unSelectedColor = UIColor.lightGray
let selectedColor = UIColor.white
let appColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 168.0/255.0, blue: 225.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 2436:
            offsetHeight = 44.0
        default:
            print("unknown")
        }
    }

    addTabView()
}

func addTabView() {

    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TabBarView", owner: self, options: nil)


    tabBarView.frame = CGRect(x:
        0 , y: Helper.getScreenHeight() - AppConstants.kTabBarheight - offsetHeight, width: Helper.getScreenWidth(), height: AppConstants.kTabBarheight)
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarView)


    self.item3Btn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) //here i showed my third tab bar item initially


}

@IBAction func tabBarBtnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var isViewToChange = false
    let currentIndex = self.selectedIndex
    var tochangeIndex = sender.tag


    self.item1Btn.setImage(item1Image, for: .normal)
    self.item2Btn.setImage(item2Image, for: .normal)
    self.item3Btn.setImage(item3Image, for: .normal)
    self.item4Btn.setImage(item4Image, for: .normal)
    self.item5Btn.setImage(item5Image, for: .normal)




    switch sender.tag {

    case 0:

        self.item1Btn.setImage(item1Selected, for: .normal)

        if currentIndex != 0{
            isViewToChange = true
            tochangeIndex = 0
        }
        else{
            (self.viewControllers?[currentIndex] as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }


    case 1:

        self.item2Btn.setImage(item2Selected, for: .normal)

        if currentIndex != 1{
            isViewToChange = true
            tochangeIndex = 1

        }
        else{
            (self.viewControllers?[currentIndex] as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }

    case 2:



        if currentIndex != 2{

            isViewToChange = true
            tochangeIndex = 2

        }
        else{
            (self.viewControllers?[currentIndex] as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }

    case 3:
        self.item4Btn.setImage(item4Selected, for: .normal)

        if currentIndex != 3{

            isViewToChange = true
            tochangeIndex = 3

        }
        else{
            (self.viewControllers?[currentIndex] as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }

    case 4:


        self.item5Btn.setImage(item5Selected, for: .normal)
        if currentIndex != 4{

            isViewToChange = true
            tochangeIndex = 4

        }
        else{
            (self.viewControllers?[currentIndex] as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }


    default:
        break

    }

    if isViewToChange {

        let _ = self.selectedViewController?.view
        let _ = self.viewControllers?[tochangeIndex].view
        self.selectedIndex = tochangeIndex

    }
}


func hideTabbar() {

    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    var frame = tabBarView.frame
    frame.origin.y = Helper.getScreenHeight() + 200
    tabBarView.frame = frame

}

func showTabbar() {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = false
    var frame = tabBarView.frame
    frame.origin.y = Helper.getScreenHeight() - AppConstants.kTabBarheight -  offsetHeight
    tabBarView.frame = frame

}

}
```

here i have aded methods for you to either show the tab bar of hide as we push into the stack of each tab bar item..

Here added few images for your understanding

[image: this is the interfacebuilder where i have added a tab bar controller and its child view controller]

[image: this is custom tab view image]

and also dont forgot to set the tag for each button in tab bar view, so that when any button clicked, same method is called and we handle it from there

Comment: @MdRashedPervez did you add tabbarcontroller in storyboard and assigned the SampleViewController as its class and and also added all your view controllers as tabbar's child view controller ?